# Wallpaper not scaled to the device's display

Tags: java, android, android-wallpaper

I want to set the image as **wallpaper** of the device by clicking on a button,

I set the click listener (**setWall**) but the image is not scaled to the device's display.

```
imageBrought = getIntent().getExtras().getString("appMomentImage");         
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageBrought).dontAnimate().into(imagePreview);

    setWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageBrought).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {

                    try {

                       WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setBitmap(resource);


                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Wallpaper Has Been Set!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your device metrics with this and then just pass to your image that size

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    metrics.heightPixels;
    metrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: it gives me this error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wallpapaersapp.appspot.com/o/Wallpapers%2FiOS%202.jpg?alt=media&token=4b5d568b-f86d-4fe2-ac42-94cbc25cd486"

Comment: I got into this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551226/bitmap-getwidth-on-a-null-object-reference