# Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

I just got into this problem on the line CreateScaledBitmap, I am trying to set this image as device's wallpaper and I need to scale this image to the device, thats why I am doing this method but unfortunately I cant fix this Bitmap width() error

```
            setWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageBrought).into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

                    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
                    int width = metrics.widthPixels;


                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);

                    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(AppMomentSelected.this);
                    wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
                    wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);


                    try {

                        wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: `bmap2` mustn't be `null` make a `null` checking before performing an action.

Comment: What is the error, post your log

Comment: @Rino Hello, I did an if statemant and bmap2 is null.. I dont know why.. in any case, this is the error: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.nicco.wallpapersapp, PID: 11771
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                      at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:658)
                      at com.example.nicco.wallpapersapp.AppMomentSelected$1.onClick(AppMomentSelected.java:85)

Comment: @Yupi Hi Yupi, I did an if statemant and yeah.. bmap2 is null.. I dont know why, how could I fix it? look, I updated the code in the question

Comment: What is `imageBrought` probably in it is problem? And can you this part change to `getBytes("UTF-8");`

Comment: @Yupi image brought is this: imageBrought = getIntent().getExtras().getString("appMomentImage"); its a string that I converted into an inputstream, I tried to change the UTF but it gives me an error if I put UTF-8

Comment: `Log` the `imageBrought` and see what will be shown in `Log` console is it `null` or correct value

Comment: @Yupi I typed the Log statement for the imagebrought string and into the Logcat area in Android Studio, selecting "Debug", it appears a Firebase link which is what I passed, its the image from my database, if I click it, it appears this message: {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object"
  }
} under the firebase link it appears these two errors:Failed to send current screen to service And  Discarding data. Failed to send event to service

Comment: To open up image it needs to have extension `.jpg` or `.png` on end of your link assuming that everything else is correct.

Comment: @Yupi yeah, I passed this string which is the image link but it doesnt have the .jpg extension.. how could I add it? look, this I am doing it through this URL link: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/wallpapaersapp.appspot.com/o/Wallpapers%2FiOS%202.jpg?alt=media&token=4b5d568b-f86d-4fe2-ac42-94cbc25cd486

Comment: @Yupi I manually added the ".jpg" in the end, it keep saying bmap2 is null

Comment: Yes you have `.jpg` in url but way you want to represent is `Bitmap` is complicated and probably not possible. You can decode for example `Uri` but not actually image `Url`. I will present some another step to download image

Comment: @Yupi I manually uploaded this image on firebase storage and added the link url download intot he database, its weird .. if its very complicated I may download this image into the android device..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Url` of an image from your `Firebase` but approach you use to get `Bitmap` from `Url` is not efficient and probably not possible. Simple thing you need to do is to use some custom `library` for downloading images for example **Picasso**
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Add to your `app gradle`: `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

And now you can use `Picasso` to download image from `Url` and convert to `Bitmap`:

```
                DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

                int height = metrics.heightPixels;
                int width = metrics.widthPixels;
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(AppMomentSelected.this);
                wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
                wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);

                Picasso.with(this)
                .load(imageBrought)
                .resize(width, height)
                .into(new Target() {
                 @Override
                  public void onBitmapLoaded (final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                 /* Save the bitmap or do something with it here */
                 wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
         }
    });
```

Comment: look the question on top, I updated it with your solution, it works but I have a question, is it sure now, watching the code on top updated thanks by you, that the image gets scaled into the device?

Comment: I think `Picasso` offers `resizing` option I will update the answer.

Comment: I tried on the Nexus 5X emulator and it works fine but on my mom's Huawei it doesnt :/ its not scaled the image, it is zoomed

Comment: You can hardcode `width` and `height` also putting the exact number

Comment: how can I know that? I mean people may have different screen size, is there a way to fit it automatically? I am searching too on the web

Comment: Try this code to get `width` and `height` according to screen size and provide into `Picasso resize()` something like: `Point size = new Point(); display.getSize(size); int screenWidth = size.x; int screenHeight = size.y;`

Comment: it's probably because of the OS, my mother's phone is old.. it still has got kitkat, I am sure that the new Android phones it works, thank you for your dedication sir, have a nice day!